# URL href does not work well in js

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble because link does not redirect.

Once I click on button. I get all values I should get in js, and in debugging mode if I go step by step it redirect to url set in function. It is not understandable for me because in debuging mode it works in normal not

```
<td><center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>" id="rolna"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td>
```

Script I use

```
   <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("kolicina").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("rolna").value;

            window.location.href = "materijali.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: It works well when you click on the button, but otherwise it doesn't? What is this "otherwise" situation?

Comment: No i do not get any error.

Comment: I thought on debugging mode, because when I go step by step it works well, if I am in normal mode it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Mistake here was only to change button type.

If a  element has type="submit", clicking it submits the form, and therefore prevents execution of JavaScript click event handler assigned to this element.

```
<td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()" value="<?php echo 'R-' . $id_print ;?>" id="rolna"> <i class="icon-cart"></i></button></center></td> 

<script>
   function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("kolicina").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("rolna").value;

      window.location.href = "materijali.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y;
  }
</script>
```

I have posted an answer in case someone face the similar problem.

Comment: Did you mean `<button type="button"` ?

Comment: yes, made mistake while typing. Thanks for the comment